# database foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have tables a and b; `b` references `a` via foreign key.

I copied a using:

```
create table c select * from a;
```

Now, I want to delete c only, but I got a foreign key constraint error.  How do I remove c without removing b?

Comment: run show create table x for each of your tables and post the results here.

Comment: Doesn't make sense - based on what you provided, there's no foreign key constraint on table `c` (the table you want to delete)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the foreign keys, then the table.